# Automatic deployment from remote github repo to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github

I like to deploy a foreign (it doesn't belong to me) github repository on new commits to the master or any other branch to heroku automatically.
So on every commit, the heroku app gets updated.

Heroku only lets me deploy my own repos for my own github account.

Forking the foreign repo is not an option because I would have to update the fork manually, which just would shift the problem.

Comment: There's got to be a way that you can "watch" a repository for pushes and configure notifications to trigger a script, but I haven't been able to find a common method. Good question - how to enable a webhook for a repository that's not yours.

Comment: You could create a fork and then use cron to fetch the remote and merge it into the fork, say once a day.